# Php/mySQL connection to remote server, fatal error, connection timeout

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I've got one droplet at DigitalOcean and one webspace with domain at another hosting provider. I don't have access to anything other than ftp on the other server. On that other webspace I've got a php script which I want to remotely connect to my mySQL db on my droplet. I've opened the port 3306 in the firewall, added a user with access to the table from % and changed the row starting with "bind-adress" (also tried commenting out) in the configuration file. Still I get an error like this when trying to connect:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000] 
[2002] Connection timed out' in {the url to the script that's trying to connect}:19 
Stack trace: #0 {the url to the script that's trying to connect}(19): PDO->__construct('mysql:host={my droplet public ip}, '{username}', '{password}') #1 {main} 
thrown in {the url to the script that's trying to connect} on line 19
```

And the connection part in php looks like this:

```
$db = new PDO('mysql:host={droplet public ip};port=3306;dbname={database name};charset=utf8', '{username}', '{password}');
```

What am I doing wrong?!

Comment: Have you tried to connect the DB from a remote MySQL Client ?

Comment: I downloaded MySQL Workbench and connected successfully from my own computer..

Answer (score 0):

When I contacted the support of the "other hosting company" they told me that neither incoming or outgoing requests to another database was allowed on their servers. Despite that they told me earlier this morning that outgoing requests was allowed.